# What module is causing cache clean everyday around 13.30 o'clock

Tags: magento2, varnish

Everyday around 13:30 o'clock something is running a cache clean function in our code.

How can find the module?

[2022-06-28T13:30:08.670600+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.719469+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.928245+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.947380+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COLLECTION_DATA"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.949102+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["REFLECTION"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.953678+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.956040+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.956458+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.956781+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION_API_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.972854+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\Uri\Uri":"http://babygeardk-purge.swarm.powr.host:80/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.972927+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.973789+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:08.974535+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.913340+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.913797+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.914080+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.914344+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COLLECTION_DATA"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.914606+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["REFLECTION"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.914868+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.915130+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.915390+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.915646+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION_API_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.917627+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\Uri\Uri":"http://babygeardk-purge.swarm.powr.host:80/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.917693+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.917963+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.918229+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:09.921906+00:00] main.INFO: Cron Job
[2022-06-28T13:30:10.749799+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\Uri\Uri":"http://babygeardk-purge.swarm.powr.host:80/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:10.749947+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:10.750331+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2022-06-28T13:30:10.750612+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

**UPDATE**, Thank you for your reply, simonthesorcerer. I have added the logging function. Now I get the following in the log. Why does this invalidate the full Varnish cache?

[2022-07-07T08:42:11.549272+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p_104366","cat_c_502","cat_c_701","cat_c_700","cat_c_2","cat_c_256","cat_c_500","amasty_xlanding_page_1","amasty_xlanding_page_2","amasty_xlanding_page_3","amasty_xlanding_page_4","amasty_xlanding_page_5","amasty_xlanding_page_6","amasty_xlanding_page_7","amasty_xlanding_page_9","amasty_xlanding_page_11","amasty_xlanding_page_12","amasty_xlanding_page_13","amasty_xlanding_page_14","amasty_xlanding_page_15","amasty_xlanding_page_16","amasty_xlanding_page_17","amasty_xlanding_page_18","amasty_xlanding_page_19"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2022-07-07T08:42:11.549326+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Exception: only here for debugging in /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/InvalidateLogger.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Logger.php(60): Magento\Framework\Cache\InvalidateLogger->execute()
#1 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Logger.php(48): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Logger->log()
#2 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache.php(96): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Logger->clean()
#3 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Proxy.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Cache->clean()
#4 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DeferredCacheCleaner.php(76): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Proxy->clean()
#5 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Processor/CleanCache.php(50): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DeferredCacheCleaner->flush()
#6 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\CleanCache->afterUpdateMview()
#7 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#8 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#9 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Cron/UpdateMview.php(31): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\Interceptor->updateMview()
#10 [internal function]: Magento\Indexer\Cron\UpdateMview->execute()
#11 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(368): call_user_func_array()
#12 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(879): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->_runJob()
#13 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(840): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->tryRunJob()
#14 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(280): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->processPendingJobs()
#15 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->execute()
#16 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod()
#17 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()
#18 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch()
#19 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cron.php(86): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch()
#20 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Console/Command/CronCommand.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Cron->launch()
#21 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand->execute()
#22 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#23 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#24 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#25 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#26 /home/babygear_dev/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#27 {main} [] []

Comment: if it had been at the hour it could be the cron that magento has internally to wipe cache at midnight server time

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your cronjobs using `crontab -l` in the shell to see if it is something obvious.

If not:

It looks like the string is logged in `vendor/magento/framework/Cache/InvalidateLogger.php` method `execute()`.

I'd add logging for a debug backtrace there, to see where the function call originates. May require some additional digging into the code to find the root cause after that.

The extended function could look something like this:

```
    public function execute($invalidateInfo)
    {
        $this->logger->debug('cache_invalidate: ', $this->makeParams($invalidateInfo));
        // added:
        try {
            throw new \Exception("only here for debugging");
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->logger->critical($e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

This should send the stacktrace to the `exception.log` or `system.log` file and show you which part of your code is responsible.

**UPDATE**

After looking at the stack trace, I think the "problem" lies here:

`Magento\Indexer\Cron\UpdateMview->execute()`

...which then runs this:

`Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\CleanCache->afterUpdateMview()`

One or more indexers get updated, and afterwards the cache gets cleared.
I don't know if it really clears *all* cache, or if it sends special entities to the cache which get cleared - by looking into `private function cleanCache()` I see `$this->context->getIdentities()` and would expect the latter.

Maybe you have a product import running very often which updates *everything*? Like, the price, stock or other attributes of *every* product, even if there's no change? This would explain why it does a full cache clear.

Comment: HI, Thank you for your reply. I have added the function, but I don't get why this invalidate the full Varnish cache - please see debug.log in question

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: why reindexing automatically flushes so much of the cache, while not having methods for re-warming the flushed cache, is a big magento annoyance. I might want to reindex my search index but not want every single category and products block to be wiped!
And it puts a cache wipe in its internal cron too, with no explanation